Dimensional analysis of field operator for massive real scalar fields
I'm trying to make dimensional sense of the field operator resulting from the canonical quantization of the massive real scalar lagrangian:
$$\mathcal {L}=\frac 1 2 [\partial_{\mu}\phi]^2-\frac 1 2 m^2\phi^2$$
associated with the Klein-Gordon equation. In most texts, the general solution for the field operator is given by:
$$\hat{\phi}(x)=\int \frac {d^3p} {(2\pi)^{\frac 3 2}}\frac 1 {2E_p}(\hat{a}_pe^{-ipx}+\hat{a}_p^\dagger e^{ipx})$$
(in some cases, a factor $\sqrt{2E_p}$ is absorbed into the $\hat{a}_p$ and $\hat{a}_p^\dagger$ operators).
Now, all this is written using natural units, as is the norm in this field, so it must be turned into a SI-units expresson. It's clear that the two exponentials must give an adimensional quantity, and  therefore a factor $\frac 1 {\hbar}$ must be included in the exponent, like:
$$e^{\frac {-i} {\hbar} px}$$
However, what I'm left with is a factor $\frac {d^3p} {2E_p}$. I could introduce a factor 1/c, changing it into $\frac {d^3p} {\frac {E_p} c}$, but that still leaves me with something having the dimensions of a momentum squared, if I'm not wrong, while I believe the field operator should be an adimensional quantity.
Can anybody help here?
Thanks

it must be turned into a SI-units expresson Why bother? Most physicists work in natural units until they get a quantity they’re going to actually measure in SI units.

I believe the field operator should be an adimensional quantity. Do you understand what the dimensions of $\mathcal L$ have to be in natural units?

Why would you want to do this at all? Sounds super messy and completely useless.

In natural units where $\hbar=c=1$ every unit can be converted to some power of a mass. This “mass dimension” is 0 for the action; -1 for $x$, $y$, $z$, and $t$; -4 for $d^3x,dt$; 4 for $\mathcal L$; 1 for $\partial_\mu$; 1 for $\phi$; 1 of course for $m$; and 1 for $p_i$ and $E$.

Note that, with your mode expansion of the field, the creation and annihilation operators are not dimensionless.

I want to remind the OP that $\phi^2$ is a number density, up to some c and $\hbar$.

@Ghoster: I'm doing this out of curiosity (a bit of  background here: I'm not a student trying to solve some homework, I'm just self-studying QFT for my interest). In the end, if a physicist wants to apply this formulr to a real-life case, they would have to introduce the $\hbar$ and c, wouldn't they? I wanted to understand how difficult this was with a complex formula, and it doesn't seem straightforward (but may be my limited understanding).

Physicists would use QFT to calculate, say, a measurable cross section for some scattering process and get something that might be proportional to the inverse square of the collision energy. They would then restore $\hbar$ and $c$ to convert an inverse square energy to an area. They would not put the $\hbar$’s or $c$’s in all the intermediate steps of this calculation because it would be tedious and unnecessary.

$\hat\phi(x)$ is not even a measurable quantity. It’s an operator in Fock space. It’s a means to an end of calculating something measurable like an area, a time, a distance, an energy, etc.

@Ghoster: not sure I understand why the creation/annihilation operators are not dimensionless. I believe e.g. $\hat{a_p}=\frac {\hat{x}m\omega+i\hat{p}} {\sqrt{2{\hbar}mw}}$ and it seems dimensionless to me (unless I'm missing something)

@octonion I think the OP wants to see $\hat\phi(x)$ with $\hbar$ and $c$, not $\mathcal L$.

That’s the raising and lowering operator for a simple harmonic oscillator. The creation and annihilation operators for a quantum field are similar but not identical. What QFT textbook are you using?

@Ghoster: QFT for the Gifted Amateur. I found the PDF on  the net and thought I would give it a try. Do the creation/annihilation operators for a quantum field include the $\frac 1 {\sqrt{2E_p}}$ factor I was mentioning in my question?

Conventions vary, and I don’t have that book. Presumably your book has other equations involving $\hat a_p$ from which the dimensions can be determined. For example, look at the commutators. Don’t they involve a Dirac delta function on the right side? That isn’t dimensionless.

Thanks, your comments and @octonion answer provide the clarity I needed

You might find this question interesting. It deals with dimensional analysis in QED rather than scalar QFT.

If you want to find the dimensions of $\phi$ in units where $c$ and $\hbar$ are not set to one, you first need to restore these constants in your Lagrangian density so that each term has the same dimensions.
One way to do this is
$$\mathcal {L}=\frac 1 2 \left[-\left(\frac{1}{c}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\phi\right)^2+\left(\nabla \phi\right)^2- \frac{m^2c^2}{\hbar^2}\phi^2\right].$$
This isn't the only way to do this, since you can multiply the overall expression by arbitrary powers of $\hbar$ and $c$, but if you can find the dimensions of $\phi$ using this convention you can find it with any other.
Now use the fact that the action $S=\int dtd^3 x  \mathcal{L}$ and the dimensions of $S$ are energy times time, to get that $\mathcal{L}$ is an energy density, $[\mathcal{L}]=EL^{-3}$.
But from the above expression we also have $[\mathcal{L}]=L^{-2}[\phi]^2$, so the dimensions of $\phi$ in this convention are $$[\phi]=\sqrt{E/L}.$$

This answers the question about the dimensions of $\phi$ (up to the ambiguity of overall multiplication by $\hbar$ and $c$), but how is it consistent with the expression for $\phi$ in terms of ladder operators?
$${\phi}(x)= C\int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3\sqrt{2E_p}}\hat{a}_pe^{-i(p\cdot x)/\hbar}+\text{h.c}$$
where $C$ is some constant factor constructed out of $\hbar, c$.
Note that $\hat{a}_p$ has the commutation relation
$[\hat{a}_p,\hat{a}^\dagger_{p'}]=(2\pi)^3\delta^{(3)}(p-p')$, so we must have that the dimensions of $\hat{a}_p$ are the same as the dimensions of momentum to the power of $-3/2$. Any ambiguity in this equation in terms of overall factors $\hbar, c$ we can just absorb into $C$.
Using the fact that the dimensions of momentum are $ET/L$, the formula for $\phi$ in terms of $\hat{a}$ tells you that the dimensions of $\phi$ are
$$[\phi]=[C] \left(ET/L\right)^{3/2}E^{-1/2}=[C]E(T/L)^{3/2}$$ Matching to the previous convention for $\phi$ we have that $C=c/\sqrt{\hbar}.$
So everything is consistent, and you can choose how you want to deal with the factor $C$ (you can use a different convention for $\phi$ or $\hat{a}$ and move it to the expression for $\mathcal{L}$ or the commutation relation if you want).

Hi @octonion, thanks for your answer. It gives some different perspective to my question.

For some reason I had assumed all operators to be dimensionless, and you clearly show it's not the case. However, using this new piece of information, I'm still not able to insert all $\hbar$ and c in  the formula. I understand from @Ghoster that's not the way a physicist would work, but just for the sake of curiosity, if you could point at how it can be done I'd appreciate it

I explained how the dimensional analysis for the ladder operators works out. Note that I think you forgot a square root in the formula for the field in terms of $\hat{a}$. This is consistent with both Peskin and Schroeder and Weinberg.

Thanks a lot @octonion, this is something I can think about and work on

@GiovanniNieddu A simple way to see that operators should have dimensions even in 1-d quantum mechanics is the Hamiltonian for a free particle, $H=\frac{p^2}{2m}$. Since $m$ has dimensions, clearly either $p$ or $H$ must have dimensions. And in fact both do; momentum and energy, respectively. If you want to frame it in fancy language, the spectra of these operators correspond to dimensionful observables, so we must be able to scale the operators consistently in any physically realistic equations so that their spectra can also be scaled to an arbitrary system of units.
